# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'story' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['story/(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\Z']

Tags: javascript, html, django, jinja2

I'm getting this error: `NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'story' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['story/(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\Z']`

For this line in my template:  .

When I am trying to print it to the screen `({{ subject.list.0.id }})` it prints the id without any problem, but for some reason when I am trying to pass it here  `<a href="{% url 'story' id=subject.list.0.id %}">`, it doesn't work.

the URL:  `path("story/<int:id>", views.story, name="story")`,

the view:

```
def story(request, id):
story = Story.objects.get(id=id)
last_post = story.posts.all()[::-1][0]
return render(request, "story.html", {
    "posts": story.posts.all(),
    "deadline": last_post.deadline,
})
```

The page view:

```
def index(request):
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
user_genre = user.genres.all()
stories = [{'list': Story.objects.order_by("-likes").all()[0:20], 'popular': 'true'}, 
            {'list': Story.objects.all()[::-1][:20], 'new': 'true'}, ]
for genre in user_genre:
    stories.append({'list': Story.objects.filter(genres=genre)[0:20], "genre": genre})
print(stories)
return render(request, "homepage.html", {
    "genres": Genre.objects.all(),
    "user": User.objects.get(id=request.user.id),
    "stories": stories
})
```

*The 'subject' in the homepage template is from `{% for subject in stories %}`.

****Edited:****

When I try to execute `stories=Story.objects.all()` and then use it in the template as `<a href="{% url 'story' id=subject.id %}">link</a>`, it works amazingly. However, my intention is not to use all the posts. Instead, I am attempting to pass stories to the template using the following structure:

```py
stories = [{'list': Story.objects.order_by("-likes").all()[0:20], 'popular': 'true'},
           {'list': Story.objects.all()[::-1][:20], 'new': 'true'}, ]
```

Now, an issue arises when I attempt to print `{{ subject.list.0.id }}`. It successfully prints the ID, but I am unable to pass the ID in the following manner: `<a href="{% url 'story' id=subject.list.0.id %}">`. Unfortunately, this approach does not work.

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

```
{{ stories }}<br><br>
{{ subject }}<br><br>
{{ subject.list }}<br><br>
{{ subject.list.0 }}<br><br>
{{ subject.list.0.id }}<br><br>
```

[image]

What can be the problem? What am I missing? I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you define an `app_name` in your **urls.py**?  If, for example you defined one, like `app_name = "home"`, then you would need to modify the template to `<a href="{% url 'home:story' id=subject.list.0.id %}">`

Comment: Are you using javascript there somehow? If not, remove it from the tags. It specifically says that the value is empty - I would check that value render again.
@raphael this does not matter - it would show error for `url` tag.

Comment: Can you include the output from print(stories) ?

Comment: @Julkar9 Yes sure, look at what I've edited.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Thank you for your comment but no, I am not using any javascript.

Comment: I think the issue is with genre business and genre cookbook, the 'list' parm have empty queryset , so {{ subject.list.0.id }} is undefined in these two cases.

Comment: Comment the `for genre in user_genre` and the next line `stories.append...` and then try running the code.

Comment: I will add a jinja snippet in the answer to handle this edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not checking if `{{ subject.list.0 }}` exists or not. A simple workaround is to access `{{ subject.list.0.id }}` only if length of `subject.list > 0`.

Try this jinja snippet

```
{%for subject in stories%}
    {% if subject.list|length > 0 %}
        <a href="{% url 'story' id=subject.list.0.id %}">link</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Here I setup a small project for a solution, my side working fine please check your side

## views.py

```
def AllstoriesView(request):
  data = Story.objects.all()
  context = {
      'data': data
  }
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def GetStoryView(request, id):
  story = Story.objects.get(id=id)
  context = {
      'story': story
  }
  return render(request, 'singlestory.html', context)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 
    path('story/', AllstoriesView,name='story'),
    path('story/<int:id>', GetStoryView,name='story'),
 
]
```

## Html Code for listing Stories

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
     Index | Page 
{% endblock title %}
   
{% block body %}
  <!-- Using slicing -->
  <h3>Using slicing</h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Title </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{data.0.title}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'story' id=data.0.id %}">link</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <hr> <br> <br>


  <!-- Using For loop -->
  <h3>Using For loop</h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for i in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{i.title}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'story' id=i.id %}">link</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock body %}
```

## Html Code for retrive Stories

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Single story</h3> <br> <br>

    <li>{{story.title}}</li>

</body>
</html>
```

## admin panel

[image]

## Browser Output

[image]

Comment: First, thank you so much for your answer! Thanks to your answer, I realized that the issue is in the 'stories' variable. I will be happy if you look at what I have edited.

Comment: Your welcome Please mark as right answer if you are satisfied